# Air/Protruding rubber seal on a brake caliper piston - is this normal?

Tags: toyota, brake-calipers, rav4

I'm replacing the brake rotors and pads on my 2012 Toyota Rav4 (V4 engine) and as I'm doing the rear wheels, I noticed that as I was pushing back the brake caliper piston that it quite a bit of air inside it (in the rubber seal). Is this normal? The other wheels did not have kind of air inside it and there was no protrusion; the piston black rubber seal and piston metal tube was perfectly flush with one another.

Here are some images:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you pushed the pistons too far back? Do they need to go back so far?

Comment: @SolarMike I put an old brake pad in front of the piston and pushed it back as far as it can go with the piston compressor hand tool. I did it with all my other wheels as well, in order to get the caliper frame to fit back into the caliper bracket.

Comment: I only push the piston back as far as it needs to go - and also I remove any crud of the edge of the rotor to help with that...